# Mapping an array field to a C# string list with Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

As shown in the picture I have a groups field with an array of string values.
However, I am getting an exception when trying to map it to a `List<string>` property.

Something like `Error converting value \"[134706634,134706635]\" to type System.Collections.Generic.IList[System.String]'`

I tried using some various attributes that elasticsearch provides but none worked. A json converter attribute works fine but need to write a lot of code to make it work the way I want.

Is there a cleaner and more native way to do this with NEST ?

C# Code:

```
 var groupQuery = await
     elastic.SearchAsync<CorrelationGroup>(s => s
             .Query(q => q
             .Bool(b => b
             .Must(
                  m => m.ConstantScore(c => c
                       .Filter(f => f
                       .Term(x => x.Type, counterType))
                   ),
                  m => m.ConstantScore(c => c.
                        Filter(f => f
                       .Term(x => x.TypeValue, counterTypeValue))))))
             .Index("correlation-groups").AllTypes());

 public class CorrelationGroup
 {
     [Text(Name = "type")]
     public string Type { get; set; }

     [Text(Name = "type_value")]
     public string TypeValue { get; set; }

     public List<string> Groups { get; set; }
 }
```

Source json file:

`[
  {
    "type": "APN",
    "type_value": "internet",
    "groups": [150994936,150994940]
  },
  {
    "type": "APN",
    "type_value": "internet",
    "groups": [150984921,150984922]
  },
  {
    "type": "APN",
    "type_value": "internet",
    "groups": [150984917,150984918,150984921,150984922]
  }
]`

My template is:

```
{
    "template": "correlation-groups",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 2,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "index" : {
            "store" : { "compress" : { "stored" : true, "tv": true } }
        }
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
    {
        "string_template" : { 
            "match" : "*",
            "mapping": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "match_mapping_type" : "string"
         } 
     }
    ],
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "properties": {
                "type": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "type_value": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "groups": { "type": "string"}
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

[image: LOGSTASH CONF]

[image: INDEX]

Comment: It seems your array is actually a string. See the escaped doubles quotes around the array `\"[134706634,134706635]\"` ? It's very likely that your `groups` array has been stringified at some point and stored as a string.

Comment: Would be great to see how do you create mapping for index and how do you index data.

Comment: @Val I specified type string in the template (thats what I understood from docs) should I use something else instead ?

Comment: That's correct, however, the issue seem to lie upstream in the code that indexes your document. Very likely that your client code is stringifying that array somehow and neither sending a list nor an array.

Comment: @Rob Please see edit for the template I am using

Comment: @Val Please see the template in my edit. Is the dynamic part that is messing up ?

Comment: I don't think so, I think you're sending `{"groups": "[1,2,3]"}` instead of `{"groups": [1,2,3]}`

Comment: @Val Yeah I think the problem is in my json doc which is `"groups": "[150984917,150984918,150984921,150984922]"`

Comment: Clearly yes, but like @Rob said, we need to see your client code in order to figure out where it itches

Comment: @Val Please see the edit for all of those. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can I see a sample line of your `groups.json` file?

Comment: @Val please see the Source json file in edit

Comment: It's funny, because without changing anything to any of the above, the groups get stored correctly for me (i.e. as an array of int and not as a stringified array). Exact same logstash configuration, groups.json file and ES template...

Comment: In your head plugin, can you take the "Other request" tab and run this `GET correlation-groups/_search`? Can you post a screenshot of the documents you see? The "Structured search" tab is not that great as checking the types of your fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to your template; Within the `__default__` mapping, because you have specified `groups` to be of type `string`, the incoming property is being *stringified* and persisted in Elasticsearch as a string. The Logstash codec will be correctly sending the `groups` property from your source json as a number array but will be persisted as a string because of the default mapping you have.

To rectify, change the `__default__` mapping to

```
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "properties": {
            "type": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "type_value": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "groups": { "type": "integer" }
        }
     }
 }
```

If you only have one type within the index, you may want to explicitly define a mapping for that type instead.

Once you have done this, change your C# POCO to

```
public class CorrelationGroup
{
    [Keyword]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Keyword(Name = "type_value")]
    public string TypeValue { get; set; }

    public List<int> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

If you're using Elasticsearch 5.x, you should use the `keyword` type that maps to the older `not_analyzed` `string` type. Additionally, you only need to specify the name for `TypeValue` as it uses snake casing (NEST client understands camel case naming coming from Elasticsearch and will map to pascal case POCO property names). Finally, I've changed the `Groups` property to be an `int` list.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer. I tried your suggestion but now logstash is complaining that it cannot convert string to int.

Comment: You'll need to delete that index and create it again (I'm guessing this is OK for you to do at this point). Logstash should be sending through the correct json; can you also output to `stdout` to check?

Comment: Alright so by looking at the stdout seems like it works. One thing that I had to do was make the json file single line. However, I dont see the `groups` column in GUI (head plugin). Any idea why that is ?

Comment: Alright code works as well. I think this `head` plugin also deceived me that it wasnt working. It does not show my groups column but it is there :) Cheers for the help.

Comment: haven't looked at HEAD plugin for a little while. I'd recommend using curl or Kibana's Sense to check: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html